# I am looking for a noun to suit a specific individual, who "Taught" my previously innocent daughter some very bad behaviors

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a special needs adult daughter, in a shared living arrangement with roommates, who was ALWAYS kind, sweet, and very cooperative. We'd never heard any negative commentary regarding "Sally", prior to an unknown roommate arriving on the scene. "Daisy", a higher functioning girl, from an unfortunate background, easily charmed both of us, while possessing a measured, devious character, and being very persuasive, literally taught & modeled for Sally, that it wasn't necessary to do ANYTHING staff asked, including basic hygiene and chores. Before that time, we'd never received a hint of a problem. Since then, our Sally has increasingly been a "stinker" to her staff and caregivers. What is a good noun for such a person, who "demonstrates" for an innocent the "ways of the world"?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: What connotation are you looking for? Are you looking for an insult for a special needs(?) girl?

Comment: *Mentor*? Sally's got it.

Answer (score 1):

With respect, I encourage consideration of a more nuanced appellation. The genteel assignment is “unfortunate influence.” However, simply branding the ill mannered girl will do little to aid and assist your daughter’s happy and peaceful enjoyment of life free of the burden of someone else’s boorish sport degrading her behavior.

Using the term to firmly inform upper level staff and management, or your fellow associated guardians, of the unacceptability of the current arrangements. To describe the offending interloper’s discreditable influence to those in a position of authority and responsibility to rightly require their intervention is the way in which whatever appellation you ultimately find to be appropriate will have a desirable outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The colloquial term "bad apple" or "rotten apple" comes to mind.

Comment: Neither term explicitly conveys the idea of teaching bad behaviors to another.

Comment: I disagree. This is derived from the phenomenon of rotting fruit, using apples as an example. "All it takes is one bad apple" and the entire apple batch is ruined. "Bad apple" implies a negative person who spreads their influence.

Comment: @KillingTime You may be confusing this with "bad seed".

Answer (score 0):

**corrupter / corruptor** (n.)

> One who or that which corrupts: in various senses. OED

**corrupt** (v.)

> **To change from good to bad in morals, manners, or actions** [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corrupt)

---

> He was a **corrupter** of virtue, an habitual drunkard and gamester, a
> notorious blasphemer and freethinker, a fitting companion for my Lord
> March, finally, and the company into whose society he had fallen.
> [William Makespeace Thackeray; *The Virginians*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Virginians/KoI6AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a%20corrupter%20of%20the%20innocent%20manners&pg=PA295&printsec=frontcover)

> Xenophon specifies that Mausolus, not happy about abandoning his camp,
> gave Agesilaus a large sum or money with no apparent compensation. The
> Spartan was thus described as a **corruptor** who not only did not
> give gifts, but received them. [Vincent Azoulay; *Xenophon and the
> Graces of Power*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Xenophon_and_the_Graces_of_Power/GkaEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20corrupter%20lead%20him%20astray&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover)

> Other rulers had set an equally bad example at the beginning of the
> century. In July, 1706, Duke Louis of Wurtemberg married, as an
> additional wife, his courtesan, Gravenitz, the “**corrupter** of the
> country,” as she is still called in Wurtemberg. [August Bebel; *Woman
> and Socialism*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Woman_and_Socialism/0sbCDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20corrupter%20set%20a%20poor%20example&pg=PT63&printsec=frontcover)